# Why are the state variables passed into the filter not equal to the state variables defined by each [sensor]_config matrix?

Tags: navigation, ekf, ros-melodic, ros-kinetic, robot-localization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to get a deeper understanding on how ekf_localization_node works.
At the moment I am stuck in interpreting the output of the debug file.

In particular, from the output of that file, I am trying to understand what the line `Update indices` on the debug file indicates:

**Case 1:**
Measurement topic name is:

- odom0_twist

  Update indices are:
  [2        3        4        6        7        8        9        10       11       14       ]

[EDIT 1:]
**Case 2:**
Measurement topic name is:

- imu0_acceleration
- imu0_pose
- imu0_twist

  Update indices are:
  [2        3        4        8        9        10        11        14        ]

From the source code file [ekf.cpp](https://github.com/cra-ros-pkg/robot_localization/blob/19126874894fadf0fa57e8c634748a56d8066326/src/ekf.cpp#L68-L90) I get that the filter checks which measurement state variables actually get passed into the filter. Only if a state variable value is not 'nan' or 'inf' the index is pushed back into `updateIndices`, which is then printed to the debug file.

I assume that the index value refers to the order/index of the state vector elements.
And from the documentation I get the impression that the state vector elements are ordered as follows:

0: position x
1: position y
2: position z
3: rotation roll
4: rotation pitch
5: rotation yaw
6: velocity X
7: velocity Y
8: velocity Z
9: velocity roll
10: velocity pitch
11: velocity yaw
12: acceleration X
13: acceleration Y
14: acceleration Z

Therefore I conclude that the line `Update indices` from the debug file is telling me that following state variable are passed into the filter: 2:position z , 3:rotation roll, 4:rotation pitch, 6: velocity X , 8: velocity Z, 9: velocity roll    etc..

This does not match with the [sensor]_config matrix (a.k.a true/false matrix) values that specify what variables should be fused into the final state estimate (see configuration file below).

Could some help me to understand what the line `Update indices` on the debug file indicates?

[EDIT 2:]

Code comments confirm that 'Update indices', in effect, describes which state variables that are passed into the filter.

The question that remains is:
**Why are the state variables passed into the filter not equal to the state variables defined by each [sensor]_config matrix?**

```
# My configuration for the robot_localization EKF node
frequency: 10

two_d_mode: true
debug: true
debug_out_file: /home/rob/catkin_ws/src/ekf/ekf_debug_file.txt
publish_tf: false

odom_frame: odom
base_link_frame: base_link
world_frame: odom
# map_frame: map


odom0: /odom_noisy
odom0_config: [false, false, false,
               false, false, false,
               true,  true,  false,
               false, false, true,
               false, false, false]


odom0_differential: false


imu0: /mobile_base/sensors/imu_data_raw

imu0_config: [false, false, false,
              false, false, true,
              false,  false,  false,
              false, false, true,
              true, false, false]

imu0_differential: false
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/361211/why-are-the-state-variables-passed-into-the-filter-not-equal-to-the-state-variables-defined-by-each-%5Bsensor%5D_config-matrix?/) by [Roberto Z.](https://answers.ros.org/users/39640/roberto-z./) on ROS Answers with karma: 500 on 2020-09-09

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are two reasons:

1. If your raw sensor data is given in a different coordinate frame than the EKF uses, the matrix in the config specifies what data to use in the *sensor* frame, and the raw filter is using the indices in the target frame (body frame or world frame, depending on what you're fusing).
2. If you have `two_d_mode` on, then for every measurement you get on a given sensor, we always fuse a `0` value for all 3D variables. If we didn't do this, your state estimate would quickly diverge. So looking at your odom example, you have X velocity, Y velocity, and yaw velocity enabled. Since you also have `two_d_mode` on, I would expect Z position, Z velocity, roll, pitch, roll velocity, pitch velocity, and Z acceleration to all get measured too (again, we just pass it a measurement of 0 with a tiny covariance). Here are the indices you posted:

```
[2        3        4        6        7        8        9        10       11       14       ]
```

Note that those indices match expectations.

---

Originally posted by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) with karma: 13689 on 2020-09-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Roberto Z.](https://answers.ros.org/users/39640/roberto-z./) on 2020-10-16**:
I can confirm that setting `two_d_mode: true` is what causes to include all 3D-space state variables (Z, roll, pitch, their respective velocities, and Z acceleration) to the filter.

I was expecting that `two_d_mode: true` would cause 3D-space state variables to be ignored.
The reason being that the system of linear equations depends only on the state variables of interest.
In fact if I set  `two_d_mode: false` less state variables are considered -> smaller sub-matrices -> less calculations steps required by each filter iteration.

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2020-10-16**:
Right, but that requires a separate kinematic model, and we only have one, and it does estimation in full 3D. I painted myself into a corner when I designed it, and adding other kinematic models isn't trivial. I simply don't have the cycles to add that feature.